# How to identify when fetch is completed in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I am making an api call in my created() hook, but there are a few things in my app I want to trigger AFTER the api call is finished, but I'm not sure how to do that.  On average my API call takes about 5 seconds to return a huge chunk of json (terrible i know).  In the example below, the logging statement prints well before the api call has finished.

snippet from component:

```
<script>
  created() {
    this.myEndpoint = 'testserver.com'
    fetch(this.myEndpoint)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
      for(let i=0; i<body.length; i++){
        this.job_execs.push({
          'version': body[i].version,
          'platform': body[i].platform.name,

        })
      }
    })
    .then(console.log('print AFTER the api call is completed'))
    .catch( err => {
      console.log('Error Fetching:', this.myEndpoint, err);
      return { 'failure': this.myEndpoint, 'reason': err };
    })
  },
};
</script>
```

I have tried moving the console.log statement to the mounted() hook, but this did not work either.

I believe I could achieve what I want using:

```
  $(window).on('load', function(){
    console.log('this logs after the entire page loads')
    });
```

But I'm sure there is a more elegant vue.js solution.

How do I identify in vue.js when the api call in my example has completed

Comment: in this function: `.then(body => { /* your for loop */ console.log('API Finished') })`

Comment: thanks this worked - and will work as a temporary solution, but was hoping there was something built into vue that could determine if the page was loaded or all the components were loaded

Comment: I believe that in my current project - vue thinks the component is loaded despite the API call taking 5 seconds.  So for example if I want to implement a loading animation, I'm not sure what to hook into to make sure the page is loading

Comment: You could do it here `.then(() => console.log('print AFTER the api call is completed'))` however the previous `then(body...` needs to return a promise such as `return Promise.resolve()`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn `then` calls do not need to return promises if they are synchronous. In particular, returning `Promise.resolve()` from a `then` call is always redundant. I'm providing this clarification here as I see you've amended your question

Comment: I usually use `async/await`, so I didn't realize that `then` returned a promise if nothing was returned. Though it returned whatever the code specified.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine in concept. 
The problem is

```
.then(console.log('print AFTER the api call is completed'))
```

Even though `promise.then` calls register async handlers, the calls themselves are evaluated synchronously, they are just supposed to take async callback functions as arguments. When you call

```
.then(console.log('print AFTER the api call is completed'))
```

`console.log('print AFTER the api call is completed')` is evaluated synchronously (logging out your message) and its return value (`undefined`) is then passed to `.then` as the callback.

Pass in a function here instead and you should see your log come at the appropriate time:

```
.then(() => console.log('print AFTER the api call is completed'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function to the `then` statement. What you have will execute the `console.log` and pass its result to the then statement (which is `undefined/void`).

```
created() {
  this.myEndpoint = 'testserver.com'
  fetch(this.myEndpoint)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
      for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
        this.job_execs.push({
          'version': body[i].version,
          'platform': body[i].platform.name
        })
      }
    })
    .then(() => console.log('print AFTER the api call is completed'))
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error Fetching:', this.myEndpoint, err);
      return {
        'failure': this.myEndpoint,
        'reason': err
      };
    })
}
```